# google.maps.places is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website that loads 3 seperate "views" of a location via Google Maps, Street and Places.

Please see my code below:

I have finally gotten Maps and Street view to work properly but am struggling a bit with this one.

I have a tab that displays the same as map but with places added.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=....&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myLattitude = <?php echo $data["lattitude"]; ?>;
var myLongitude = <?php echo $data["longitude"]; ?>;
var poiMap;
var infowindow;

function initializePoi() {
            var poiCentre = new google.maps.LatLng(myLattitude, myLongitude);

            poiMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('poi-canvas'), {
                center: poiCentre,
                zoom: 15
            });

            var request = {
                location: poiCentre,
                radius: 500,
                types: ['store']
            };
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(poiMap);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
        }

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: poiMap,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(poiMap, this);
            });
        }
```

Now This initializes properly but the console throws the following error:
TypeError: **google.maps.places is undefined**

I just want to know why I get this error, I like having clean errorless code.

The places do actually show up properly and everything.

Comment: If you got your answer please check it as correct.

Comment: How do you do that ? new to the forum :)

Comment: Below the up/down arrows, at the left of each answer it is a check mark. Click on that, to mark the answer as correct. This way, you save time from other members :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You should add the option `libraries=places` in the Google API URL

In your case you should replace the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=....&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=....&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap&libraries=places"></script>
```

Look at the end of the `src=""`

Comment: Not really, JsFiddle isnt displaying anything :( Server key issues I suppose

Comment: Ha, What seemed to have worked is placing the link to the maps script in the body along with your advice, thanks so much Meriano :)

Comment: Also note to clear your browser cache if your JavaScript doesn't work as you expect after the code modifications. May this can help.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you have to use https instead of http.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=....&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap&libraries=places"></script>`

Everything else is same as previous answer mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since the top answer addresses the vanilla version, this is for those using google-maps-react:

add libraries: ['places'] to your GoogleMapReact Component:

```
   <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: apiKey, libraries: ['places'] }}
    ...
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React.

```
import { Wrapper as MapsWrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";

// Note libraries prop.
<MapsWrapper apiKey={'YOUR_API_KEY'} libraries={['places']}>
  <ChildComponent />
</MapsWrapper>
```