# Google maps autocomplete place undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add the autocomplete feature of google maps. 
But i am getting the an error "place undefined".

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = places.getPlace();
        var address = place.formatted_address;
        var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
        var mesg = "Address: " + address;
        mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
        mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
        alert(mesg);
    });
});
   </script>
   <span>Location:</span>
   <input type="text" id="txtPlaces" style="width: 250px" placeholder="Enter a location" />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try replacing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

As mentioned in [Get a Key/Authentication](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key),

> All Google Maps JavaScript API applications require authentication.

Likewise, [Versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions) stated that

> You can indicate which version of the API to load in your application by specifying the `v` parameter of the Google Maps JavaScript API bootstrap request.

If adding API key doesn't work for you, this SO post - [google.maps.places is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997672/google-maps-places-is-undefined) might give you the needed solution.

Comment: I tried replacing the script tag as you gave. But i am not getting any autocomplete suggestions. and sometimes it works only for a particular letter. like it gives suggestions only for letter 'B' and nothing else.