# TypeError: Cannot read property 'places' of undefined while using Google Location API inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to configure the Google location API to use in a form input. I am getting the following error:

[image: TypeError]

I am using the following script tag inside my index.html file:

[image: script tag]

Here is the code for the component inside which I am trying to use the Google API:

```
import React from 'react'
/* global google */
const google = window.google = window.google ? window.google : {}

import { FormContainer, ModalTextInput } from './styles'
import '../styles.css'
import { Modal, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

import TelInput from './IntlTelInput'

class EditDetailsModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.autocompleteInput = React.createRef();
    this.autocomplete = null;
    this.handlePlaceChanged = this.handlePlaceChanged.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.autocompleteInput.current,
        {"types": ["geocode"]});

    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.handlePlaceChanged);
  }

  handlePlaceChanged(){
    const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.props.onPlaceLoaded(place);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.handleClose} className="editModal">
                <FormContainer>
                    <Modal.Header className="editModalHeader">
                      <Modal.Title>Edit Personal Details</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Form>
                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicName">
                            <ModalTextInput customPlaceholder="Name"/>
                          </Form.Group>

                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <ModalTextInput customPlaceholder="Email ID"/>
                          </Form.Group>

                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPhoneNumber">
                          <TelInput className="formInput"/>
                          </Form.Group>
                          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicName">
                            <ModalTextInput ref={this.autocompleteInput} customPlaceholder="Country you will work in"/>
                          </Form.Group>
                          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="submitBtn">
                            Save details
                          </Button>
                        </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                </FormContainer>
        </Modal>
      )
  }

}

export default EditDetailsModal
```

I've tried a number of fixes but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: Try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997672/google-maps-places-is-undefined/20997725

Comment: No this didn't work for me. The error in that question states that places is undefined whereas the error I am getting is cannot read 'places' of undefined suggesting that 'google.maps' is undefined.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue. You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) to do this. Also, the script tag appears to be missing the required API Key parameter, but if you removed this, then please do also let us know or just use `key=YOUR_API_KEY`.